# How does iterating over HashMaps work in memory: Rust

Tags: data-structures, rust, hashmap, heap-memory

I know how to iterate over a HashMap in Rust, however, I am a little confused about how this works in memory. How do we iterate over values that are not stored sequentially in memory? A detailed explanation of the code below at the heap and stack level would be much appreciated.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

let name = vec![String::from("Charlie"), String::from("Winston"), String::from("Brian"), String::from("Jack")];
let age = vec![50, 5, 7, 21];

let mut people_ages: HashMap<String, i32> = name.into_iter().zip(age.into_iter()).collect();


for (key, value) in &people_ages {
    println!("{}: {}", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the intro of the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html), it is mentioned that the implementation relies on a [C++ implementation of SwissTables](https://abseil.io/blog/20180927-swisstables).
This page contains illustrations about two variants: « flat » and « node » based.

The main difference between these two variants is *pointer stability*.
In the « node » based version, the key-value pairs, once inserted, keep their address in memory even if the hash is reorganised.
In the « flat » version, some insertions/removals can make the previous key-value pairs be moved in memory.

When it comes to the Rust implementation, I am not experienced enough to be certain of any specific detail, but I tried this simple example based on yours.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let name = vec![
        String::from("Charlie"),
        String::from("Winston"),
        String::from("Brian"),
        String::from("Jack"),
    ];
    let age = vec![50, 5, 7, 21];
    let mut people_ages: HashMap<String, i32> =
        name.into_iter().zip(age.into_iter()).collect();
    let mut keys = Vec::new();
    let mut values = Vec::new();
    for (key, value) in &people_ages {
        keys.push(key);
        values.push(value);
        let key_addr = key as *const String as usize;
        let value_addr = value as *const i32 as usize;
        println!("{:x} {:x} {}: {}", key_addr, value_addr, key, value);
    }
    // people_ages.insert("Bob".to_owned(), 4); // mutable and immutable borrow
    println!("keys: {:?}", keys);
    println!("values: {:?}", values);
}
/*
55e08ff8bd40 55e08ff8bd58 Brian: 7
55e08ff8bd20 55e08ff8bd38 Charlie: 50
55e08ff8bd00 55e08ff8bd18 Winston: 5
55e08ff8bce0 55e08ff8bcf8 Jack: 21
keys: ["Brian", "Charlie", "Winston", "Jack"]
values: [7, 50, 5, 21]
*/
```

The commented out line (insertion) is rejected because we cannot alter the hashmap while keeping references to its content.
Thus, I **guess** (I'm not certain) that the implementation does not rely on the « node » based variant since we cannot take benefit of the *pointer stability* it provides (due to the ownership model in Rust), and **probably** it relies on the « flat » variant.

This means that we can expect that the key-value pairs associated with the same hash are tightly packed in memory, and iterating over them should be very similar to iterating over a vector: regular progression (with some skips however) very friendly with cache prefetch.
Printing the addresses tends to confirm that guess (however the test is not complete enough), and shows a backward progression.